# How to filter the data filtering based on specific frequency from FFT analysis?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, data-analysis

I got set of deflection data that I analyse using fft to find two major peaks at two frequencies. How can I convert the original data to only have set of deflection values that correspond to only one of the frequencies from fft analysis?

[Deflection Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF6W7.png)

```
T = 1.0 / Fs #my time step
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y,n=N_fft) #fft on signal
xf = np.arange(0,Fs,Fs/N_fft) #time
sample_freq = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(len(y), d=T)
pos_mask = np.where(sample_freq > 0)
peak_freq = freqs[power[pos_mask].argmax()]

freq_fft = yf.copy() 
freq_fft_tol=0.25 #tolerance around the main peak
for i in range(len(freq_fft)): #filtering out everything but the meain peak +-tolerance frequencies
       if np.abs(sample_freq[i]) > (peak_freq + freq_fft_tol):
             freq_fft[i]=0
       if  np.abs(sample_freq[i]) < (peak_freq - freq_fft_tol):
             freq_fft[i]=0   
 
filtered_sig = scipy.fftpack.ifft(freq_fft) #converting fft single frequency data back to deflection values
```

And here's what it looks like in the end. Blue is original values and orange are new ones which are reduced in amplitude. I would expect some points to be the same and a lot of other filtered out...
[IFFT compared to original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3NFU.png)

Comment: You are filtering out frequencies in the frequency domain and expect to see 'some points' filtered out of the time domain!? Think of it this way: If you filter out all frequencies except one specific non-zero frequency, then the signal in the time domain will be a perfect sine wave. No 'points' will be 'filtered out' there.

Comment: Ahhh...could I then use this sine wave as the selector to either include or exclude some points thus assigning them to that frequency? Not sure how would I go about getting the phase for this right, as different points would be selected based on it...